# Data set file not found in python

Tags: python, dataframe, statistics, data-mining

I am coding a python program to read a data set file writing this line:

```
df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\user118\Desktop\StudentsPerformance.csv')
```

This line works, but I have to upload this project as an assignment , so the computer path must be changed. I think about putting the csv file in the project folder and i did and wrote this line:

```
df = pd.read_csv ("StudentsPerformance.csv")
```

but it gave me an error saying that the file isn't found. Where to correctly put the file in the project folder? Or what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

To read your csv file with a `df = pd.read_csv ("StudentsPerformance.csv")` line you should put it right next to executing .py file.
To do that you can just read your csv file using full path like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\user118\Desktop\StudentsPerformance.csv')
```

and than write `df.to_csv('StudentsPerformance.csv')`

After that you would be able to read your csv as you wanted using

```
df = pd.read_csv('StudentsPerformance.csv')
```

Comment: Is there any other way ? As I can't use the full path and I don't understand how to put it right next to executing .py file?

Comment: @DemaShaker, I meant that if you can use full path before uploading your project, you should use this line just once and than delete this it to save your .csv file within project, and after that keep "df = pd.read_csv ("StudentsPerformance.csv")" in your program, so whomever downloades your project would be able to run it.

Comment: I wrote them like this and it gave me the same error: df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\user118\Desktop\StudentsPerformance.csv')
df = pd.read_csv ("StudentsPerformance.csv")

Comment: Would you write what you mean, please?

Comment: hmm, that is quite strange because just now I've checked it on similar
X = pd.read_csv('/Users/johnsmith/Desktop/Fixed_Partial_Dataset_1.csv', sep=',')
X.to_csv('test.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',sep=',')
and it was totally fine. And 'test.csv' was completely fine and I opened it without any problems.
Also if this wouldn't work you could always find where your .py file located and drag csv manually to that folder, but I don't understand why the previous code isn't working.@DemaShaker

Comment: @DemaShaker, you forgot to save your file using df.to_csv('StudentsPerformance.csv') between those 2 lines